# When was congenital-analgesia (aka congenital insensitivity to pain), the inability to feel pain, clinically documented? How rare?

Tags: life-expectancy, history, neuropathy, pain-tolerance

**When was congenital-analgesia (aka congenital insensitivity to pain), the inability to feel pain, clinically documented?**

**How rare is it really?**

**Is it hereditary? Or just a sporadic fluke mutation?**

I know this condition sounds like it would be a lot of fun (since one doesn't feel pain), but this can be an extremely dangerous situation to be in since one can't feel when they have broken bones, have a life-threatening infection, feel the burns of a stove, and may engage in risky behavior, etc. (since they don't feel the consequences of pain). So **what is the life expectancy of someone with congenital-analgesia?**

Answer (score 5):

> When was congenital-analgesia (aka congenital insensitivity to pain), the inability to feel pain, clinically documented?

It was first reported in 1932 in this paper:

Dearborn, G. V. N. (1932). A case of congenital general pure analgesia. *Journal of Nervous and Mental Disease*, *75*, 612-615. http://dx.doi.org/10.1097/00005053-193206000-00002

However, I tried reading it, the print is very faded and near-impossible to read.

> How rare is it really?

1 in 125 million

From: 
Daneshjou, K. et al. (2012). Congenital insensitivity to pain and anhydrosis (CIPA) syndrome; a report of 4 cases. *Iranian Journal of Pediatrics*, *22*, 412–416.

But in this paper on the epidemiology in Japan, it's estimated at 1 in 600,000–950,000

From: 
Haga, N., Kubota, M., & Miwa, Z. (2013). Epidemiology of hereditary sensory and autonomic neuropathy type IV and V in Japan. *American Journal of Medical Genetics Part A*, *161*, 871-874.

> Is it hereditary? Or just a sporadic fluke mutation?

It's hereditary:

Congenital insensitivity to pain with anhidrosis (CIPA), also known as hereditary sensory and autonomic neuropathy type IV (HSAN IV)

Kim, W., Guinot, A., Marleix, S., Chapuis, M., Fraisse, B., & Violas, P. (2013). Hereditary sensory and autonomic neuropathy type IV and orthopaedic complications. *Orthopaedics & Traumatology: Surgery & Research*, *99*, 881-885.

> So what is the life expectancy of someone with congenital-analgesia?

There's age distribution of the population in Japan:

[image]

It doesn't say life expectancy, but it seems that it won't be past 40 years.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks!